# Как добавить, убрать клаcс с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, css

Есть такой код HTML

```
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="list-item">
        <ul class="add-list">
          <li class="add-list-item">
            <a href="" class="link-1">Ссылка 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="add-list-item">
            <a href="" class="link-2">Ссылка 2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="add-list-item">
            <a href="" class="link-3">Ссылка 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item">
        <ul class="add-list">
          <li class="add-list-item">
            <a href="" class="link-1">Ссылка 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="add-list-item">
            <a href="" class="link-2">Ссылка 2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="add-list-item">
            <a href="" class="link-3">Ссылка 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Как будет правильно написать скрипт, чтобы при клике на ссылку с классом `.link-3` только к родительскому `li.list-item` добавлялся класс `.new-class`, а при повторном клике класс `.new-class` убирался? Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
let li = document.getElementsByClassName('list-item');
for (let i of li) {
  i.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('link-3')) this.classList.toggle('new-class');
  })

}
```

```css
.new-class a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item">
    <ul class="add-list">
      <li class="add-list-item">
        <a href="#" class="link-1">Ссылка 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="add-list-item">
        <a href="#" class="link-2">Ссылка 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="add-list-item">
        <a href="#" class="link-3">Ссылка 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <ul class="add-list">
      <li class="add-list-item">
        <a href="#" class="link-1">Ссылка 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="add-list-item">
        <a href="#" class="link-2">Ссылка 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="add-list-item">
        <a href="#" class="link-3">Ссылка 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let linkItem = document.querySelectorAll('.list-item');

for (let i = 0; i < linkItem.length; i++) {

  linkItem[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = event.target;

    if (target.className === 'link-3') {
      this.classList.toggle('active');
    }

  });

}
```

```css
.active {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item">
    <ul class="add-list">
      <li class="add-list-item">
        <a href="" class="link-1">Ссылка 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="add-list-item">
        <a href="" class="link-2">Ссылка 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="add-list-item">
        <a href="" class="link-3">Ссылка 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <ul class="add-list">
      <li class="add-list-item">
        <a href="" class="link-1">Ссылка 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="add-list-item">
        <a href="" class="link-2">Ссылка 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="add-list-item">
        <a href="" class="link-3">Ссылка 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```